# Image click will load specific text in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of images, and an array of text. There are 3 images on the page. I would like to have the user click on an image, and depending on which image they choose, a different text will pop up. I am having trouble getting the click to work on the images and getting to the appropriate text. Clicking image1.jpg will get you item 0 in the transText Array, and so on.

Here are my arrays of images and text

```
var images =["image1.jpg","image2.jpg","image3.jpg","image4.jpg","image5.jpg","image6.jpg"];
var picNames =["Double Bacon Cheeseburger", "Fresh Fruit", "Oatmeal", "Hummer SUV", "Subway", "Bicycle"];
var transText = ["Meat produces up to 16 pounds of C02 per 1 lb of meat, and requires 1,847 gallons of water to produce", "Fresh fruit, while requiring less water to produce,\n is often brought in from far away,\n adding to carbon emissions.\n They also can spoil quickly.", "Cereal grains require low water amounts to produce,\n have a long shelf life, \n and are readily available all year round in all parts of the country", "A Hummer SUV will produce 813 grams of C02 per mile.\n The average commuter will travel 30 miles each day round trip. \n That's 24.54 kg of C02. \n Every day.", "Subways emit X amount of C02 per day.", "The best source of energy for travel is yourself.\n Biking or walking is the least harmful way to travel"];
var playTrack = false;
var imageNum = 0;

//Image Loading Loop
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {                
var imageObj = images[i];
imageObj.src = "images/" + images[i];
imageObj.onload= (function(i){
            return function(){

            }
        })(i);
}
```

Here is where I am trying to load the next image on click

```
function nextImage() {
    document.getElementById("imageWindow").src = "images/" + images[imageNum];
    imageNum++
    if (imageNum === images.length) imageNum = 0;
        else 
        playTrack = true;
        document.getElementById("imageWindow").innerHTML; 
}
```

Here is my HTML

```
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div><a href="#" onclick="nextImage('changeState')"></a></div>
<div>
<img id="imageWindow" src="images/image1.jpg" HEIGHT="300">
</div>
<h3 id = "picNames(0)">Double Bacon Cheeseburger</h1>
<p></p>
<div>
<img id="imageWindow" src="images/image2.jpg" HEIGHT ="300">
<h3 id = "picNames(1)">Fresh Fruit</h1>
<p></p>
<div>
<img id="imageWindow" src="images/image3.jpg" HEIGHT ="300">
</div>
<h3 id = "picNames(2)">Oatmeal</h1>


<script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added span tags along with your images which have display property set to none. Onclick of an image, the span innerHTML is set to the array text.

```
   <div><a href="#" onclick="nextImage('changeState')"></a></div>
    <div>
    <img id="imageWindow" src="images/image1.jpg" HEIGHT="300" onclick="myFunction(0);">
    <span class="popuptext" id="popup0" style="display:none;"></span>
    </div>
    <h3 id = "picNames0">Double Bacon Cheeseburger</h1>
    <p></p>
    <div>
    <img id="imageWindow" src="images/image2.jpg" HEIGHT ="300" onclick="myFunction(1);">
    <h3 id = "picNames1">Fresh Fruit</h3>
    <span class="popuptext" id="popup1" style="display:none;"></span>
    <p></p>
    </div>
    <div>
    <img id="imageWindow" src="images/image3.jpg" HEIGHT ="300" onclick="myFunction(2);">
    </div>
    <h3 id = "picNames2">Oatmeal</h3>
    <span class="popuptext" id="popup2" style="display:none;"></span>



<script>


var images =["images/book2.jpg","images/book3.jpg","images/book4.jpg","image4.jpg","image5.jpg","image6.jpg"];
var picNames =["Double Bacon Cheeseburger", "Fresh Fruit", "Oatmeal", "Hummer SUV", "Subway", "Bicycle"];
var transText = ["Meat produces up to 16 pounds of C02 per 1 lb of meat, and requires 1,847 gallons of water to produce", "Fresh fruit, while requiring less water to produce,\n is often brought in from far away,\n adding to carbon emissions.\n They also can spoil quickly.", "Cereal grains require low water amounts to produce,\n have a long shelf life, \n and are readily available all year round in all parts of the country", "A Hummer SUV will produce 813 grams of C02 per mile.\n The average commuter will travel 30 miles each day round trip. \n That's 24.54 kg of C02. \n Every day.", "Subways emit X amount of C02 per day.", "The best source of energy for travel is yourself.\n Biking or walking is the least harmful way to travel"];
var playTrack = false;
var imageNum = 0;

//Image Loading Loop
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {                
var imageObj = images[i];
imageObj.src = "images/" + images[i];
imageObj.onload= (function(i){
            return function(){

            };
        })(i);
}

function nextImage() {
    document.getElementById("imageWindow").src = "images/" + images[imageNum];
    imageNum++;
    if (imageNum === images.length) imageNum = 0;
        else 
        playTrack = true;
        document.getElementById("imageWindow").innerHTML; 
}

// When the user clicks on <image>, open the popup
function myFunction(n) {
    // hide already opend popups by class name
    function hideAll() {
        var allPopups = document.getElementsByClassName("popuptext");
        for(var i = 0; i < allPopups.length; i++){
            allPopups[i].style.display = "none"; 
        }        

    }        
    hideAll();

    var thisPopup = "popup" + n;
    var popup = document.getElementById(thisPopup);
    popup.innerHTML = transText[n]; 
    popup.style.display = "block";

    // hide all popups again after a minute
    setTimeout(hideAll, 60000);

}

</script>
```